# Showing $x^4+x^2+x+1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z_3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, alternative-proof

$x^4+x^2+x+1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z_3}$. So since there are no roots there are no linear factors. From here do you just try to factor it as a product of 2 quadratics and show it that this leads to a contradiction? Is that the only way? Furthermore can we assume these quadratics are monic? why? Thanks yall!

Comment: Basic properties of finite fields imply that the product of irreducible linear and quadratic polynomials of $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$ is equal to $x^9-x=x(x^4-1)(x^4+1)$.
This means that if your polynomial has no common factors with neither $x^4-1$ nor $x^4+1$, it must irreducible. Euclid's algorithm for the win.

Comment: And, as you know that there are no linear factors you can leave out $(x-1)(x+1)=x^2-1$ that is a factor of $x^4-1=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)$. So only $x^2+1$ and $x^4+1$ remain. The latter is the product of two irreducible qx^4+1uadratics:
$$x^4+1=x^4+4==x^4+4x^2+4-4x^2=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2).$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, your comments could be an answer

Comment: @lhf I have given that argument (or one nearly identical to it) as an answer more times than I care to admit. Adding repetitive material won't improve the quality of the site IMHO. I rather suspect the site as whole will become worse. Also, it would have the air of trying to get "paid" twice for the same job. If Michael wants to carry out those gcd-calculations and post the results as an answer they are welcome to do so. High rep users should show some restraint in repeating old stuff (when they should know that it will be a repetition).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, solving a system of equations is the only way to show that the polynomial is irreducible. You can, however, assume that both factors are monic:

> If $f(x)=x^4+x^2+x+1$ factors as $f(x)=p(x)q(x)$, then either both $p$ and $q$ are monic, or both have lead coefficient $2$. In the latter case, you have $f(x)=2p(x)2q(x)$ and both $2p(x)$ and $2q(x)$ are monic.